# How to auto adjust column widths & row heights in excel sheet using xslt code transformation

Tags: excel, xml, xslt

I am using this xslt code to generate excel file from the xml data as input for this code.
when a mail triggered from SAP CPI i am receiving the excel file but that excel file not coming in proper format all the columns are coming in some default sizes not able to see the content of the cell fully when i opened the file  not able to  auto adjust the column widths & Row heights based one the content of the cell. Please help me to set the column widths & row heights adjusts automatically as per the content in the cell(entire content must be visible with out double clicking at the row or columns separator lines in excel sheet after downloading the file). please help in this regard.

Thank you.

```
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="urn:test.com" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Workbook>
            <Styles>
                <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
                    <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
                    <Borders/>
                    <Font/>
                    <Interior/>
                    <NumberFormat/>
                    <Protection/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s21">
                    <Font ss:Size="22" ss:Bold="1"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s22">
                    <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s23">
                    <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1"/>
                    <Borders>
                    <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                    </Borders>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s24">
                    <Font ss:Size="10" ss:Bold="1"/>
                </Style>
                <Style ss:ID="s25">
                <Borders>
                <Border ss:Position="Bottom" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                <Border ss:Position="Left" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                <Border ss:Position="Right" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Weight="1"/>
                </Borders>
                </Style>
                </Styles>
            <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
            <Table>
            <xsl:call-template name="Excel"/>
            </Table>
            </Worksheet>
        </Workbook>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="Excel">
            <Row>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
            <Data ss:Type="String">IntegrationFlowName</Data>               
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
            <Data ss:Type="String">IFlowStartTime</Data>               
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
            <Data ss:Type="String">MessageGUID</Data>
            </Cell>
            <Cell ss:StyleID="s23">
            <Data ss:Type="String">ErrorMessage</Data>                
            </Cell>
            </Row>
        <xsl:for-each select="//MessageProcessingLogs">

            <Row>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                        <xsl:value-of select="IntegrationFlowName" />
                    </Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                        <xsl:value-of select="StartTime" />
                    </Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                        <xsl:value-of select="MessageGuid" />
                    </Data>
                </Cell>
                                <Cell ss:StyleID="s25">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ErrorMessage" />
                    </Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="MessageProcessingLogs">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to specify to Excel to automatically change to width of the column according to the contents. I usually check the data I will be getting and use example <ss:Column ss:Width="50"/> to specify a width which works for the data. It's not perfect but works in most cases.

Comment: Do i need to add this syntax ss:Column ss:Width="50" in data tag or  do i need to use <ss:Column ss:Width="50"/> just above the row tag. in data tag <Data ss:Type="String"> there is already one ss:Type-String so shell i add one more by giving space which you have provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I do it :

```
<ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet name">
    <ss:Table>
        <!-- Col 1 --> <ss:Column ss:Width="50"/>
        <!-- Col 2 --> <ss:Column ss:Width="50"/>
        <!-- Col 3 --> <ss:Column ss:Width="100"/>
        <ss:Row ss:StyleID="SomeStyle">
            <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Col1 Contents</ss:Data></ss:Cell>            
            <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Col2 Contents</ss:Data></ss:Cell>            
            <ss:Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">Col3 Contents</ss:Data></ss:Cell>
        </ss:Row>
    </ss:Table>
</ss:Worksheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much working perfectly. can you share a xml tag to adjust row height also

Comment: I have also seen this, that you could try : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6481a9f1-217f-4abd-b66d-9b4ddd008d99

Comment: But by using this tag <ss:Column ss:Width="50"/> we could able to limit the width of the columns but if the content in the column is small its fitting perfectly if content of the column is larger it going out continuously in a single line. can we limit that so that total content will be fitted in the cell(i mean can we break the long single into rows by increasing the cell height) simply can we wrap the text ot content of the cell to stop going out from the cell border.

Comment: For the height you could use : <ss:Row ss:Height="3">. The reference for XML Spreadsheet is available here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140066(v=office.10)